# How to find current location of user in mkmapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

i want to find the current location of the user 
below the code for finding coordinates from the well defined adress
 hom can i find the current location of the user ..please help me

.h file
    #import 
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,retain)  MKMapView *myMapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLGeocoder *myGeocoder;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.myMapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myMapView=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    self.myMapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;
    self.myMapView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myMapView];


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

   NSString *oreillyAddress =@"india";
  self.myGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [self.myGeocoder
     geocodeAddressString:oreillyAddress completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
   {
        if ([placemarks count] > 0 && error == nil)
            {
       NSLog(@"Found %lu placemark(s).", (unsigned long)[placemarks count]);
             CLPlacemark *firstPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]; NSLog(@"Longitude = %f", firstPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude); NSLog(@"Latitude = %f", firstPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude);


         }
         else if ([placemarks count] == 0 &&
                  error == nil){ NSLog(@"Found no placemarks.");
        }
         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"An error occurred = %@", error); }
     }];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"%f",latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",longitude);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error==>%@",error);
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: what you want ,Current Location of user address or lat/long ?

Comment: current location on map

Comment: it's already you write in your code.     self.myMapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

Comment: You ask how to get location then you mark the answer right about the simulator despite your comment that it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Answer (score 4):

Define

CLLocationManager *lm;

CLLocation *location;

and then add the below mentioned code in your ViewDidLoad method

```
lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];

    location = [lm location];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    coordinate.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;


    if((location.coordinate.longitude== 0.0 ) && (location.coordinate.latitude==0.0))
    {
        UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:(@"Server Error:")message:(@"Internet Problem. Try Later !!!") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:(@"OK"), nil];
        [alert2 show];

    }

    else
    {


        coordinate = [location coordinate];

        NSLog(@"Latitude of User is %f",coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"Longitude of User is %f",coordinate.latitude);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simulator, you would need to go to: Debug -> Location -> Customer. From there set your location to the desired test point.

Answer (score 0):

To get user's current location in iOS 8

1. Add `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` in .h file.
2. `CLLocationManager *locationManager;
   CLLocation *currentLocation;`
3. ```
   locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
   if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0 && [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
   {
   [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
   }

   locationManager.delegate = self;
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
   locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
   CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
   NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);

   NSString *currentLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];
   NSString *currentLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];

   [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
   }

   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
    {
   switch (status)
   {
   case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
   case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
   case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
   {
       [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
   }
       break;
   default:
   {
       [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }
       break;
   }
   }

        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while getting core location : %@",[error localizedFailureReason]);
              if ([error code] == kCLErrorDenied)
         {
            //you had denied
         }
            [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
        }
   ```

And In your plist file Dont forget to Enter a key

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[self.mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

Comment: This is pretty much just a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20090148).